# How to center an image in an img tag using CSS background position

Tags: html, css

I am using the HTML IMG tag to source/link an image and I want to center it in a div, but I am not having much success.

My html is:

```
     <div class="alimgholder">
<img  title="<?php echo $album_title;?>" alt="<?php echo $album_title;?>" src="<?php echo $album_pic;?>">
     </div>
```

My css is:

```
              .alimgholder
             {
             width:160px;
             height:120px;
             overflow:hidden;
             float:left;
             }
             .alimgholder img
             {

             background-color: #EEEEEE;
             background-position: center 25%;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             display: block;
             }
```

Comment: Are you trying to centre the image, or the image's `background-image`?

Comment: yes i am trying to center the background-image but i am using img src to path the image

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; the `img` element will load the image from that `src` into the document, the `background-image` of the `img` will appear *behind* the image located at that `src`. You have to explicitly declare the path to the `background-image`, as follows: `background-image: url(path/to/background-image.png);`.

Comment: emmm , then wht abt the src should i leave that empty?

Comment: You should use either background-image: url(...) *or* the img tag with its src, not both. If I understand you correctly - the image is bigger then the div that contains it? and you want to center it?

Comment: yes the image is of 240px and div is 160px and i want to center it

Comment: your image is larger than the size of the placeholder. Do you want to re-size the image?

Comment: no i dnt want to resize it . i want to center it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the css for the div only -

```
.alimgholder
         {
         width:160px;
         height:120px;
         overflow:hidden;
         float:left;
         background-image: url(path/to/your_image);
         background-color: #EEEEEE;
         background-position: center 25%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         display: block;
         }
```

Now for the dynamic issue - you can use the img tag to load the image, *but hide it* and read its src only to set the background with jQuery, like that -

```
 $("#div_id").css("background-image", $("#img_id").attr("src"));
```

Comment: <img  title="<?php echo $album_title;?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $album_pic;?>);"/> i used it like thz and its working. it this rite?

Comment: for some reason I thought you have to hold your css in separate file. In that case, you can just set the style into the div <div title="..." style="background-image: url(<?php echo $album_pic;?>);"/>, instead of the img. It might be working but there is no reason to use the img tag if you're not using its src attribute ...

Comment: leeme try that ill revert back

Comment: thanks @Namma Katiee , it works as expected friend thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
.alimgholder
{
     ...
     text-align: center;
}
```

otherwise you're aligning the image's background-image.

Edit: If you want your image to be defined as the background of your div your have to load it from css and forget about your img tag:

```
.alimgholder
{
     background: url(path/to/image) center no-repeat;
     ...
}
```

Comment: sry friend i am trying to center the image inside the div whose overflow is hidden

Comment: friend as u can see from my code the image path is dynamic . its coming from database , how can i specify path in css

Answer (score 0):

if you're only having the image within the div you could use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

within your `.alimgholder` CSS code but this would center the content of the whole `<div>` horizontally.